# Mouse movement parallax on Google Map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, parallax

Is it possible to add something [like this](http://hwthorn.github.io/parallaxify/demo/galaxy.html) to Google Maps?
This demo has parallax with multiple layers, I would need only one
for map itself.

I don't nessessarily need the code because there are few tutorials how to achieve mouse movement parallax. Im more interested how to apply this to Google Maps.

My current ideas / questions?

- Would it be somehow possible to move map tiles in the background without moving Google logo?
- If not, how to make map bigger (out of browser viewport) without messing up tiles so that I could move whole map and use `overflow { hidden; }`?

Don't worry about hiding Google's credentials or messing up controls, I could add all the `divs`, controls and logo myself via `JS`.

I would be very grateful if you used [my provided jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/418/) to make your point.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference) for information on manipulating the map view.

Comment: @magreenberg Thanks for the tip but I've worked with Google Maps API in whole past month or so and I've read it many, many, many times. Unfortunately I haven't found anything that could help me to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `panTo()` function. I gave it some default numbers for the scroll effect that you can change to meet your needs.

```
$( "#map-cover" ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    myLatlng.lat() + event.pageY / 1000, 
                    myLatlng.lng() + event.pageX / 1000)
  map.panTo(newLatlng);
});
```

Make sure to add a div above the map and disable the controls on the map

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/419/)

Upon, getting additional clarification, you can add a listener to check if the map is being dragged.

```
map.addListener("drag", function() {
    dragging = true;
});

map.addListener("dragend", function() {
    dragging = false;
});
```

[Draggable map with mouse scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/422/)

Comment: That looks awesome however is there's a way to do this without sacrificing dragging? It seems that `draggable: true` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: You could. Just remove the map-cover anyplace the `mousemove` listener on the map-div. But there's going to be some weird affect on the map when you drag and move the map...

Comment: Then Im afraid I need to find other solution because dragging is very important.. I also stumbled on a similar effect when I tried to find a solution, [take a look at this](https://wellstoried.com/map).

Comment: Ok... so you need the parallax, but still need to allow for dragging instead of your original question.

Comment: I never mentioned anything about disallowing dragging.. Im looking for the effect from my previous comment's link, parallax effect on map that has same funtionality as normal map..

Comment: I've tried to make your code to work without any funny things.. Weird effect is probably happening, because after `dragend` it pans from mouse position before dragging to position after dragging which causes this effect.

Comment: Yes, my described problem occurs when drag ends and also when you hover your mouse out of map and hover it in from other side for example, Im trying to make it smoother or better yet, I should not use `panTo` when drag ends or mouse is hovered out of map so that it _reapplies/restarts_ the positioning and `panTo` code which should prevent these sudden and funny movements.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to make changes to the how you want to get the mouse positions (If it's going to be the based on the center of the map, where it last exited (I had assumed you wanted to do this in a whole window). We're not here on SO to code the entire thing for you, but show you how you could do it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't assume that you write everything for me. I'll try to make it work, if it's not going to happen. Im probably going to scale map out of viewport, move whole map's `div` and use `overflow: hidden;`